# Shift the Page title away from the logo

Tags: master-page, css, branding

I have used the following power shell commad to add our compnay logo:-

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://gvstg01:40708
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<a href="/sites/Intranet/"><img src="/sites/Intranet/SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.png"/></a>'
$webApp.Update()
```

but currently the logo and the page title are being two close , so i there a way to modify the above script to shift the text to the right, away from the logo .currently the logo and text are being displayed as follow:-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added the following and it shofted the logo:-

```
#pageTitle {position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 40px;color:white; margin-left:20px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that it is SharePoint specific, but you could do an inline style on the link, if you do not have the option to update the master page CSS to work as expected.

To do this workaround run this command:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://gvstg01:40708
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<a href="/sites/Intranet/" style="margin-right:10px" ><img src="/sites/Intranet/SiteAssets/logo_CMYK.png"/></a>'
$webApp.Update()
```

To make it work, since I do not have your master page or resulting markup, you might need to alter the margin, or try with a padding instead.

If it still does not work, you need to do the fix in the master page CSS files rather than in you logo element.

Comment: i added the folloiwng  #pageTitle {position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 40px;color:white; margin-left:20px;}